Terms/Multi-terms aggregation with null/missing values for a field
In terms aggregation, we need the count of null/missing documents as well with count of there values as well.
I know that we can use Terms aggregation with missing which requires us to provide a default value. But the problem is that the default value must be of same datatype. So for boolean datatype field, we can only use true/false as the default value but then the actual count of documents missing the field wouldn't be known. Same for integer as the values for the fields can be anything from negative max to positive max in our data source. So, any default value may match the existing field value.
Other option is to use Missing aggregation. But this would require us to combine the result of missing aggregation with the terms aggregation counts for null/empty counts.
Wanted to know if there is a simpler/cleaner way of getting the count of null/missing documents for given fields along with terms/multi-terms aggregation without having conflicts with the existing values. Missing aggregation is one, but that requires changes in client side to combine the results.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
